# Displaying SVGs on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I've recently started looking into using D3 js, following a useful Pluralsight [course](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=d3js-data-visualization-fundamentals&author=ben-sullins&name=d3js-data-visualization-fundamentals-m1-the-basics&clip=5&mode=live), where the tutor uses jsbin.com for simple demonstrations.

I have followed along and my d3 js code works within jsbin.com ([link to code](http://jsbin.com/nalikuhena/edit?html,js,output)), which gives the following output.

[image]

however doesn't seem to work when I have the content written to files and hosted on a local server.

Here's what I have (exact same as the code in the above link)

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test Header</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
//alert("hello");

var w = 500;
var h = 100;
var pad = 2;
var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];
var svg =
  d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .style("fill", "purple");

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "purple");
```

#### Result

[image]

This writes the  `Test Header` to the page, however the SVG image is not shown. Can anyone point out why this works within jsbin but not when hosting the files on a local server?

Edit: 
Its worth noting that I am trying to view this using a simple node hhtp server, and have tried viewing the content in Firefox, Firefox dev & IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is executing before the body element is declared, which is a problem because the code tries to add stuff to the body. If you move your script tag to the end of your body, it should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test Header</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: spot on! this was driving me crazy, I knew the javascript file was working as using the `alert` function works as expected, however didn't think about the script running before its time. Thanks very much!